# How can I store information securely when I can't use crypt or a hash?

Tags: passwords, php

I'm creating an application for Google Glass (technically it's [Glassware](https://developers.google.com/glass/), but whatever). The user will do the following steps when going through setup for the Glassware:

1. Go to my website, redirected via the Glassware page.
2. Get redirected to the Google OAuth page so that they can sign in.
3. Get redirected back to my OAuth Redirect URI (fancy way to say landing page).
4. Be prompted to go to a third-party website (something like Facebook, Twitter or Instagram, not sure yet).
5. Go through either the OAuth dance or an authentication dance to get an API key/OAuth key.
6. Be thankful everything is over.

So now what I have on my hands is a couple of API/OAuth tokens, a UserId internally, and a user's Google ID. I could possibly have a few more points of data, such as CreationDate and such stuff, but none as important as this data.

Now that I have all of this data, it's time to store it. It'll probably be stored in a database such as MySQL. Since I have all of this important data on a user, how do I make it secure so that hackers can't access it? I can't use a hash or PHP's [`crypt`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php), as the user will not be entering in their password every time I need to use their tokens. In fact, the user will have *no* username and password specific to my service. I realize this makes it hard to secure, however, storing all of this as plain-text seems insecure... or is it?

So how do I secure a user's tokens when the user has no password associated with my service, and the user isn't going to be logging to the service in every time I need to use their tokens?

Comment: what is the application trying to do?

Comment: @TruthOf42 You mean the purpose of the app? It's going to be (for this part) a server-side app sending notifications to different devices & also listening for pings from devices. The other side (client Google Glass) will be sending that notification and recieving notifications too.

Answer (score 1):

Have the client application send an encryption key that was randomly generated during the initial authentication process. Depending on how often you want the user to login, the key could be generated for single session or globally for the client device.

For the server application hold two copies of the authentication tokens - the first copy is encrypted by client key for persistence, the second is unencrypted but transient in the server memory. The second transient copy is deleted after the client hasn't be heard of in a while or has logged out/uninstalled.

This way a hacker with client device access doesn't have the OAuth tokens and can only abuse your specific service. A hacker with server access doesn't have decryption key and hence the OAuth tokens are useless.

However a hacker could simply alter the server application to harvest future OAuth tokens. So the web server should prohibit hot-swapping application deployments without reboot and require a console-supplied password for the server SSL certificate on boot - which the client application explicitly checks instead of the standard catch-all CA trust store.

Comment: Hmm... this looks like a great idea. One question though: what could I use to encrypt/decrypt the key?

Comment: Depends on the server-side language. For PHP, possibly the `mcrypt` library. The client side doesn't need encryption (for this particular purpose), only a random byte generator for the key; unless you get fancy with on-the-fly client TLS certificates.

Comment: Or if your supplementary question was how to encrypt the key itself - that shouldn't be required. As with all encryption keys that don't fetch in real time from peripherals (keyboard, smart card, etc), at some point you have to rely on the security of the device. In this case we are mitigating that risk through having the "complete picture" only on the server and timing out that data.